# Syntax error when adding SQL column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database called "members" and in that there's a table called "test". I'm trying to add a column to the table "test" but am getting the following error
MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax.

My SQL code:

```
ALTER TABLE 'test'
ADD COLUMN 'Email' VARCHAR(25)
NULL AFTER 'LastName';
```

Comment: 'classtest' is a string. \`classtest\` is a table. Likewise for the columns. And VARCHAR(25) is not enough for an email address.

Comment: If you paste your SQL statement that you're trying to run, someone may be able to help you here...

Comment: I forgot that I didn't need the quotes. Thanks!

Comment: In our datbase out of over a million records, more than 20% have an email _address longer than 25 characters.

Comment: You almost never want to use quotes on table and column names.  The only time you must use them is if they have spaces or funny characters in them, which is a bad idea, or if they match a SQL reserved word, which is also a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alter table classtest add column Email varchar(25);
```